# Select Count(*) over large amount of data

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, large-data-volumes

I want to do this for a Report but i have 20,000,000 of records in my table and it causes an TimeOut in my application.

```
SELECT
        T.transactionStatusID,
        TS.shortName AS TransactionStatusDefShortName,
        count(*) AS qtyTransactions
    FROM
        Transactions T 

    INNER JOIN TransactionTypesCurrencies TTC
                ON  T.id_Ent = TTC.id_Ent
                    AND T.trnTypeCurrencyID = TTC.trnTypeCurrencyID
            INNER JOIN TransactionStatusDef TS
                ON  T.id_Ent = TS.ent_Ent
                AND T.transactionStatusID = TS.ID
WHERE
    T.id_Ent = @id_Ent
GROUP BY
        T.transactionStatusID,
        TS.shortName
```

as far as i know COUNT(*) causes a full table scan and it makes my query to take too much time, im Using MS SQL 2005, any help ?

#### Edit:

The project leader tells me that the Query is just for one day it could help?

Comment: What do you mean "just for one day"?  Are there any datetime/smalldatetime columns on the transaction table? Are these columns indexed?  Is the index clustered?  As someone else asked, what is the majority of the work being performed according to the plan?  You say above that it causes a table scan yet below you say it uses an index.  Giving us a better idea of the actual existing table structure, and the actual execution plan attributes, will allow us a better opportunity to point out areas for improvement.  Without that we are guessing.

Comment: the table has a field name TransactionDate is a SmallDateTime field the main work of the table is store the transactions made by internet, once i read that using Count(*) its better that using Count(1), i have to create index to my table but taking care of the inserts because users will insert a lot of transactions and it has to be very fast. thanks (sorry about my english)

Comment: `@jmpena`: in most modern database systems (and definitely in `SQL Server 2005`) `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` behave exactly the same. The additional filtering on a date column requires changing the index so posting the whole query will help you to assist you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as far as i know COUNT(*) causes a full table scan and it makes my query to take too much time, im Using MS SQL 2005, any help ?

`COUNT(*)` can use any source that is able to give the answer, this includes indexes.

In your very case, I'd create a covering index on `(id_ent, transactionStatusID)` with `trnTypeCurrencyID`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON Transactions (id_ent, transactionStatusID) INCLUDE (trnTypeCurrencyID)
```

and rewrite the query a little:

```
SELECT  transactionStatusID, qtyTransactions, TS.shortName
FROM    (
        SELECT  T.transactionStatusID,
                COUNT(*) AS qtyTransactions
        FROM    Transactions T
        JOIN    TransactionTypesCurrencies TTC
        ON      TTC.id_Ent = T.id_Ent
                AND TTC.trnTypeCurrencyID = T.trnTypeCurrencyID
        WHERE   T.id_Ent = @id_Ent
        GROUP BY
                T.transactionStatusID
        ) TD
JOIN    TransactionStatusDef TS
ON      TS.ent_Ent = @id_Ent
        AND TS.ID = TD.transactionStatusID
```

The index will filter on `id_ent` and parallelize on `transactionStatusID`. Since you have `trnTypeCurrencyID` covered, the engine will not have to lookup the value in the table, it's already present in the index.

The `GROUP BY` clause also includes only the columns from the index so it parallelizes much better.

**Update:**

By adding `WITH (ONLINE = ON)` you can leave the table operational for the time the index is being created:

```
CREATE INDEX ON Transactions (id_ent, transactionStatusID) INCLUDE (trnTypeCurrencyID) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

Comment: this answers helps it takes down the time a lot, but i have some others Querys and i cant create several index because its a transactional table

Comment: You can add `WITH (ONLINE = ON)` option if you have enough space. This will leave the table operational for the time the index is being created.

Comment: Note that online index rebuild is only possible in Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the execution plan for the query, that will highlight the bits that are performing badly. It will tell you whether it's doing a table scan, index scan or index seek.
So that's the best place to start looking.

Do you have any indexes at the moment? The fields involved in the JOINs and WHERE clause are prime candidates - if you don't have indexes, that'll be a major factor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
COUNT(1)
```

Instead?

Also, is the join to **TransactionTypesCurrencies** required, does not seem that you use anything from it?

Comment: The problem is the scan, and I have yet to see a case where COUNT(*) outperforms COUNT(1).  SELECT * can outperform SELECT <limited cols>, depending on indexes, but even that is only marginal.  If there is a table scan then the problem is certainly to do with improper indexes.  Not always solvable without causing pain elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, true, indexes is a important factor here, and removing joins not required.

Comment: count(*) use the current index

Answer (score 0):

What is the clustered index on the transactions table?  What other indexes exist?  You could try this query to eliminate one join:

```
SELECT
    T.TransactionStatusID,
    TS.ShortName,
    qtyTransactions = COUNT(*)
FROM
    dbo.Transactions AS T
INNER JOIN
    dbo.TransactionStatusDef AS TS
    ON T.id_Ent = TS.ent_Ent
    AND T.transactionStatusID = TS.ID
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
        FROM do.TransactionTypeCurrencies AS TTC
        WHERE TTC.id_Ent = T.id_Ent
        AND TTC.trnTypeCurrencyID = T.trnTypeCurrencyID
)
AND T.id_Ent = @id_Ent
GROUP BY
    T.transactionStatusID,
    TS.shortName;
```

You could also try to use snapshot isolation before issuing the query, e.g.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;
```

To do this you must have:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
```

In general though you want to make sure you get the indexing right.  If you can't apply proper indexing on the tables for this query because it will hurt other queries, then you can consider an indexed view to maintain this count for you (at the cost of insert/update performance), or table partitioning if you are on Enterprise Edition, or occasionally running a rollup of this data in the background so that your application doesn't have to wait for it (assuming it is ok that the actual count is a bit stale).

Comment: your right i cant create index in any fields because is a transactional table and it will hurts querys, the query that i put here is just one of 5 Diferent reports (status,channels,Month/Day,etc...) ill try your response.. thanks

Comment: i cant affect the inserts, this table will never be updated just Inserts, any help knowing this ? i dont know much about views