# SDAC -RecordCount and FetchAll

Tags: sql-server, delphi, dataset, memory-management, record-count

I am using [SDAC](http://www.devart.com/sdac/) components to query a SQL Server 2008 database. It has a `recordcount`property as all datasets do and it also has the `FetchAll` property (which I think it is called `packedrecords` on `clientdatasets`). Said that, I got a few questions:

1 - If I set `FetchAll = True` the `recordcount` property returns ok. But in this case, when I have a large database and my query returns a lot of lines, sometimes the memory grows a lot (because it is fetching all data to get the `recordcount` of course).

2 - If I set `FetchAll = False`, the `recordcount` returns -1 and the memory does not grow. But I really need the recordcount. And I also wanna create a generic function for this, so I dont have to change all my existent queries.

What can I do to have the `recordcount` working and the memory usage of the application low in this case?

Please, do not post that I dont need recordcount (or that I should use EOF and BOF) because I really do and this is not the question.

I thought about using a query to determine the recordcount, but it has some problems since my query is going to be executed twice (1 for recordcount, 1 for data)

**EDIT**

@Johan pointed out a good solution, and it seems to work. Can anybody confirm this? I am using 1 `TMSCconnection` for every `TMSQuery` (because i am using threads), so I dont think this will be a problem, will it?

```
  MSQuery1.FetchAll := False;
  MSQuery1.FetchRows := 10;
  MSQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from cidade';
  MSQuery1.Open;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(MSQuery1.RecordCount)); //returns 10
  MSQuery1.Close;

  MSQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT @@rowcount AS num_of_rows';
  MSQuery2.Open;
  ShowMessage(MSQuery2.FieldByName('num_of_rows').AsString); //returns 289
```

**EDIT 2***

`MSQuery1` must be closed, or `MSQuery2` will not return the `num_of_rows`. Why is that?

```
  MSQuery1.FetchAll := False;
  MSQuery1.FetchRows := 10;
  MSQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from cidade';
  MSQuery1.Open;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(MSQuery1.RecordCount)); //returns 10
  //MSQuery1.Close; <<commented

  MSQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT @@rowcount AS num_of_rows';
  MSQuery2.Open;
  ShowMessage(MSQuery2.FieldByName('num_of_rows').AsString); //returns 0
```

Comment: You only have three choices, which you already know: 1) Use `FetchAll`, retrieve all rows, and use `RecordCount`, 2) don't use `FetchAll` and therefore don't have access to `RecordCount`, or 3) use `Count()` (which should be fairly fast, if you're using a proper `WHERE` clause to limit the row count) and then execute your query again for data. There's really no other choice.

Comment: Choice number 4 is to use the statistics that SQL-server keeps about its queries, see my answer below.

Comment: when the connection is open you have a database cursor that you're fetching from, this prevents the @@rowcount from detecting that the transaction has ended. Using a separate connection per thread is an excellent idea because that way sql-server will keep a separate rowcount per connection and will not confuse the threads.

Comment: @Johan, is there any way of having the recordcount without closing the query? Maybe closing the transaction or something else. The point is, it will be nice to have the query open and be able to get the recordcount as well.

Comment: you can use `select count(*) over ....`, but that will be very slow compared to @@rowcount. See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874888/select-count-over-large-amount-of-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your query as normal, than **close** the query

```
MSQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from cidade';     
MSQuery1.Open;     
MSQuery1.Close;
```

You need the `close` otherwise SQL-server has not closed the cursor yet, and will not register the query as 'completed'.

**and run the following query right afterwards:**

```
SELECT @@rowcount AS num_of_rows
```

This will select the total number of rows your last `select` read.
It will also select the number of rows your update/delete/insert statement affected.

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

Note that this variable is **per connection**, so queries in other connections do not affect you.

Comment: Can you please check my **EDIT** to see if this is what i should do?

Answer (score 2):

I use ODAC and I believe SDAC inherits from the same base classes and works the same way as ODAC. In ODAC, there is an option called QueryRecCount under Options in your query component. Look for TCustomDADataSet.Options.QueryRecCount in your help file.

Setting QueryRecCount = True and FetchAll = False will reduce your memory usage and give you the record count. But SDAC will run a second query in the background to get the record count so it does add a little bit of extra time to your query.

Take a look at the Devart forum entry at http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8143.

Comment: Yes, it inherits from the sabe base classes. But this property does not work all the time. Some queries do not work and I just dont know why. Also, if the query has a `top` command, the recordcount returns wrong results. Try it yourself.

Comment: do you know how much time (in average) this property adds to the query execution?

Comment: The property creates a query behind the scenes that does a select count(*) from ({your query}). I can't really give you an average time that it adds, especially since I'm using ODAC instead of SDAC. Sometimes it is a few milliseconds, sometimes a minute or two. A lot of the performance depends on your database design and the particular query you are running. Indexes, statistics, dataset size, db server settings, etc. all factor into how long it takes. I have been very pleased with the results when using it though.

Comment: Also, if you are getting incorrect results sometimes (you mentioned when you use the `top` command), post a message on the Devart forums or email their support. They are very good about answering questions posted on their forums and quickly investigate bugs.